# Spring-Kafka - How can I specify a range of partitions for Listeners using annotations?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have 3 topics and each topic has 50 partitions. I want to use @KafkaListener to specify listeners for different partitions

- Should I have one listener for each topic?
- Should I have multiple listeners for one topic, if so how can I specify a range of partitions for a topic?
- Also, out of the 3 topics, 2 topics have much more data than the third so should I have more listeners for this topic for it to be able to catch up with the load?
- And how should I choose the concurrency number?

My code so far:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableKafka
public class ConsumerConfig {

  // Factory to create the consumer classes
  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    return propsMap;
  }


  //
  @Bean
  KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public Listener listener() {
    return new Listener();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation).

> You can also configure POJO listeners with explicit topics and partitions (and, optionally, their initial offsets):

```
@KafkaListener(id = "bar", topicPartitions =
        { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "0", "1" }),
          @TopicPartition(topic = "topic2", partitions = "0",
             partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "1", initialOffset = "100"))
        })
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
    ...
}
```

One listener can listen to multiple topics, but if you have different message volumes, I would recommend a separate listener per topic; otherwise the low volume topic might not get the desired activity.

**EDIT**

You can use a SpEL expression to generate an array of partitions.

For example; two listeners, one getting the odd partitions and the other getting the evens might be configured like this...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53588657Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53588657Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so53588657", 50, (short) 1);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "odd", topicPartitions =
            @TopicPartition(topic = "so53588657",
                partitions = "#{T(com.example.So53588657Application$SplitParts).odds(50)}"))
    public void oddParts(String in) {
        // ...
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "even", topicPartitions =
            @TopicPartition(topic = "so53588657",
                partitions = "#{T(com.example.So53588657Application$SplitParts).evens(50)}"))
    public void evenParts(String in) {
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> registry.getListenerContainers()
                .forEach(c -> c.getAssignedPartitions().forEach(ap -> System.out.println(ap)));
    }

    public static class SplitParts {

        public static String[] odds(int partitions) {
            return split(partitions, i -> i % 2 == 0);
        }

        public static String[] evens(int partitions) {
            return split(partitions, i -> i % 2 == 1);
        }

        private static String[] split(int partitions, IntPredicate predicate) {
            return IntStream.range(0, partitions)
                    .filter(predicate)
                    .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .toArray(new String[0]);
        }

    }

}
```

Or you could provide them as a comma delimited list in a property and use

```
partitions = { "#{'${partition.list}'.split(',')}" })
```

Comment: Thank you Gary! How do I configure a listener to read from all partitions in a topic? It expects me to explicitly specify the partitions but we have 50 so is there a better way to specify them rather than listing all 50?

Comment: You can use a SpEL expression to create an array of partition numbers. See the edit to my answer for a couple of examples.